# INSERT INTO based on a INNER JOIN'd SELECT column not returning SELECT value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, insert, inner-join

I'm attempting to do an `INSERT` into `Accounts` based upon a `CustNo` value, with the tables connected by `AccountId`. For some reason I cannot figure out, the `SELECT cust.CustNo` column, based on the `Custs` table columns of `GivenName` and `Surname`, is not grabbing anything despite working by the same WHERE clause when tested on it's own.

```
INSERT INTO Accounts (Type, Balance, CustNo)
    SELECT 
        'Chequing', 0, cust.CustNo
    FROM 
        Custs cust
    INNER JOIN 
        Accounts ON cust.CustNo = Accounts.CustNo
    WHERE 
        cust.GivenName = 'FirstName' AND cust.Surname = 'LastName';
```

I can't think of any reason why this is not returning any errors, yet also works and grabs the correct `CustNo` as a separate `SELECT` with this same `WHERE`. Am I missing an essential field somewhere to relate these two tables, or possibly incorrectly joining them?

Comment: I would suggest adding the table definitions, and example data, along with expected output. This will help others understand your question, and help you get the best answer as quickly as possible.

Comment: I don't really understand why you are joining to Accounts at all. You don't use any of the fields from it, and if this is you inserting the customer's first account, the join will cause no results to be returned

Comment: @JamesCasey, my apologies for the lack of clarity. Type and Balance are from Accounts whereas CustNo, GivenName, and Surname are from Custs.

Comment: But if you are inserting them, they don't exist yet, so when you do the join, you get nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I did not quite end up answering my original question, I DID however find another way to accomplish what I was trying to do with a nested `SELECT` instead of an `INNER JOIN`.

For anyone else that comes by trying to `INSERT` data to one table based upon a field (My `Name`, `Surname`, and `CustNo` problem) that is in another related table, try something like this:

```
INSERT INTO Accounts (Type, Balance, CustNo)
SELECT 'Chequing', 0, (SELECT CustNo FROM Custs)//This is the solution, a nested Select
WHERE GivenName = 'FirtName' AND Surname = 'LastName');
```

Comment: You could get the same result by just removing the inner join from the query in your original post